# How to set datepicker formatting with dash or comma?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using datapicker and  I want to use date format such as "2012-12,12" or "2012.12.12" or "20121212" on input. But this is not working

This is what I tried. [http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/WArtA/]

How do I use format such as dash, comma, or only number  ?
please help

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question here on Stack Overflow, not only on jsFiddle. You've been around long enough to know that you need to do that much. Use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to use an interface that looks like jsFiddle's.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, simply switch the format in line 2 and 3:

```
 $(function(){
        $("#to").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy#mm.dd' });
        $("#from").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd' }).bind("change",function(){
            var minValue = $(this).val();
            minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
            minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate()+1);
            $("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minValue );
        })
    });
```